# Атомарность операции получения экземпляра класса на x64 приложении

Tags: c#, многопоточность, атомарность

Атомарность присваивания можно добиться с помощью [`System.Threading.Interlocked`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.interlocked(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Interlocked.Exchange(ref toItem, fromItem);
```

А вот как атомарно получить экземпляр класса атомарно, ведь у `System.Threading.Interlocked` нет метода `Read(ref object)`, есть только `Read(ref long)`?

```
TObject obj = somethingObject; 
//Сомнение атомарности. 
//Поскольку передача указателя x64 не умещается в такт процессора, 
//и не гарантирует атомарности.
```

просьба не приводить примеры с `lock`, т.к. мне они не интересны.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Операция чтения ссылки на объект всегда атомарная. Это следствие базового принципа .NET: если ваш код не содержит вызовов unsafe - вы никак не можете получить некорректную ссылку на объект.

Как следствие, всегда атомарными являются чтение int, указателей и IntPtr. Более того, чтение long тоже атомарно *на 64-битной системе* (найденный вами метод `Interlocked.Read(ref long)` предназначен для платформ x86 или AnyCPU)

Однако, надо понимать что Interlocked-операции - это не только атомарность, это еще и барьеры памяти. Поэтому читать разделяемую переменную как `TObject obj = somethingObject` нельзя - это чтение может дать устаревшие данные.

Для чтения нужно использовать метод [`Volatile.Read`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.volatile.read(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
TObject obj = Volatile.Read(ref somethingObject);
```

Comment: `Операция чтения ссылки на объект всегда атомарная` Блин это же логично! У нас x64 IntPtr будет только на x64 приложении. Вот это я тупанул.

Comment: «Для чтения нужно использовать метод Volatile.Read» судя по документации (MSDN), `Volatile.Read` гарантирует лишь барьер памяти и никаких гарантий касательно «неустаревших» данных. Кроме того, использовать V`olatile.Read` без `Volatile.Write` просто напросто бесполезно, да и в примере у автора нет подходящего кода для использования этой пары.

Comment: @ixSci барьер памяти и гарантия неустаревания данных - это одно и то же, просто первый термин - формальный, а второй - "на пальцах"

Comment: @ixSci что же до записи - то `Interlocked.Exchange` является вполне себе заменой для `Volatile.Write`

Comment: @PavelMayorov, давайте проясним, т.е. Вы утверждаете, что `TObject obj = Volatile.Read(ref somethingObject);` гарантировано вернёт последнее записанное в `somethingObject` значение? Если это так, то Вы заблуждаетесь, такой гарантии нет и барьер памяти её не даёт.

Comment: @ixSci оно вернет последнее *видимое* записанное значение

Comment: @ixSci записи через Interlocked.Exchange - видны, потому что там есть барьер записи

Comment: Барьеры нужны для окружающего кода и бесполезны для самого объекта, т.е. если бы был [псевдо]код: T1: `{ x = 1; Volatile.Write(ref obj, true);}`  и T2: `if(Volatile.Read(ref obj)) assert(x==1)` ты мы бы имели гарантию, что assert никогда не свалится с ошибкой, но никакой гарантии, что даже если первый поток выполнил запись, то второй поток эту запись прочитает даже если он условие проверит после того, как первый закончил запись. Т.е. без окружающего кода все эти Volatile.Read/Write просто не нужны.

Comment: @ixSci Вы сейчас что-то страшное рассказываете...